# TypeScript use generic function parameter in curry function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, redux

I'm trying to create a function to generate my redux action creators.

Let's say we have these types for our actions:

```js
export type DeleteAction = {
  type: typeof BLAH_DELETE;
  payload: {
    id: string;
  };
};

export type EditAction = {
  type: typeof BLAH_EDIT;
  payload: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
};

export MyAction = DeleteAction | EditAction
```

Now in the actions file, I would like to create my actions in this way:

```js
export const deleteBlah = makeActionCreator<MyAction>('BLAH_DELETE');

// Expected Behaviour 
deleteBlah({ id: '' }) // Correct
deleteBlah({ id: '', name: '' }) // Error

export const editBlah = makeActionCreator<MyAction>('BLAH_EDIT');

// Expected Behaviour 
editBlah({ id: '', name: '' }) // Correct
editBlah({ id: '' }) // Error
```

Here is the `makeActionCreator` function:

```js
export const makeActionCreator = <A extends { type: string; payload: any }>(type: A['type']) => (
  payload: ActionPayload<ExtractAction<A, A['type']>>,
) => ({
  type,
  payload,
});

type ExtractAction<A, T> = A extends { type: T } ? A : never;

type ActionPayload<T extends { payload: any }> = Pick<T['payload'], keyof T['payload']>;
```

The problem is I don't know how can I pass the action type which is provided in actions file to the `ExtractAction<A, A['type']>` so, the payload is always valid for all possible options of `A`.

Comment: How does the type `ActionPayload ` look like? I guess it would be: `type ActionPayload<A> = A extends { payload: any } ? A['payload'] : never;`

Comment: Don't know why you specify correct type corresponding to function like: `export const deleteBlah = makeActionCreator<DeleteAction>('BLAH_DELETE');

 `

Comment: @tmhao2005 Sorry I just added that one as well. Because of 2 reasons: 1) Reduce the number of imports and simplify the file. 2) Avoid repeating unnecessary data. `DeleteAction` itself has the action type so it doesn't make sense to send it again as a param, but we need that param as well :)

Comment: Ah. you meant that you can infer the payload based on the input action key?

Comment: @tmhao2005 YUP! :)

Comment: I think we can do that. Let's me think :)

Comment: Is it just me or does that have nothing to do with currying at all?

Comment: @timotgl Hmmm, you're right in some ways :D Feel free to give me your suggestions for improving the function itself ;)

Comment: @Hamid Don't have an answer, sorry. I came here because I find function currying interesting, and was a bit disappointed.

Comment: @timotgl No worries. BTW we need this style to pass the action type and access to it in return object ;)

Comment: @Hamid did you see my idea yet?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I have some idea to turn your idea work. Here are the few steps:

- First of all, we define some utils type which we can detect the type of any prop & extract the type of `payload` property as well:

```
type ValueType<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;

type ExtractPayload<A, T> = A extends { type: T, payload: infer R } ? R : never;
```

- Next, we define the return `Curry` function which receives action as argument:

```
type Curry<A> = <T extends ValueType<A, 'type'>>(arg: T) => (payload: ExtractPayload<A, T>) => {
  type: T
  payload: ExtractPayload<A, T>
};
```

- Finally, we re-write your action creator function a bit since I don't know how to declare the type for a function rather than just define only return type, so you have to create one more level of curry `makeActionCreator<MyAction>()` which is a bit annoying though:

```
export const makeActionCreator = <A>(): Curry<A> => action => payload => ({
  type: action,
  payload,
})

// Testing

const deleteBlah = makeActionCreator<MyAction>()('BLAH_DELETE');
deleteBlah({ id: '' }) // Correct
deleteBlah({ id: '', name: '' }) // Error
```

**Another solution**

Another options, you would keep your function without creating more curry level but you have to pass one more typing argument as following:

```
type Curry1<A, T> = (payload: ExtractPayload<A, T>) => {
  type: T
  payload: ExtractPayload<A, T>
};

// The function is the same but have type T as new parameter

export const makeActionCreator = <A, T>(action: T): Curry1<A, T> => payload => ({
  type: action,
  payload,
})

// Testing, it's a bit odd as specify 'BLAH_DELETE' twice

const deleteBlah = makeActionCreator<MyAction, 'BLAH_DELETE'>('BLAH_DELETE');
deleteBlah({ id: '' }) // Correct
deleteBlah({ id: '', name: '' }) // Error
```

Comment: Thanks! This one is also a good solution...But I can't mark it as an answer because it's not exactly what I want. If I find that it's not possible to apply my idea in TS, I'll mark it as an answer ;)

Comment: I dropped another proposal :) but not perfect I guess since having input more argument

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Some<U, I> = (U extends I ? true : false) extends false ? false : true;

function makeCreator<T extends MyAction["type"]>(type: T) {
  return function <P>(
    p: { type: T; payload: P } extends MyAction
      ? Some<MyAction, { type: T; payload: P }> extends true
        ? P
        : never
      : never
  ): MyAction {
    return null as any;
  };
}
```

code

```js
 { type: T; payload: P } extends MyAction
      ? OneOf<MyAction, { type: T; payload: P }> extends true
        ? P
        : never
      : never`
```

assert the argument you provided is exactly the payload type according `type` given